# C++ std::make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, make-shared

The following code snippet is from the book C++ Concurrency In Action Practical Multithreading page 152, a thread-safe stack class. My question is why the following pop function (of the thread-safe stack class) can't just `return std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data.top())` instead, where data is of type `std::stack<T>` since `make_shared<T>` returns a `shared_ptr`? Thank you in advance!

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
{
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
std::shared_ptr<T> const res(std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data.top())));
data.pop();
return res;
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the fat that `top` doesn't remove an item from a `stack`, the code is basically just error-checking around your suggestion.

Comment: @StephenNewell, I am pretty new to C++, I am used to the syntax of "res = ....." in other programming languages, for saving result to a local variable. Forgot the code here is just calling a copy constructor for share_ptr. Thanks! It makes sense to me now.

Comment: Please show the code of your proposed version. Where does it call data.pop()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This because you need to store value in temporary variable (res), before it will destructed by pop() call.

```
std::shared_ptr<T> pop()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(m);
    if(data.empty()) throw empty_stack();
    // data.pop(); will remove top element
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::move(data.top())); // top element has not changed
}
```